# What does "close over" mean in this react article?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learing react pattern - render props.
So I head to this article, but when I was going to finish it,
I found myself not able to figure out the meaning of "close over".

At the bottom of the [page](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html):

> In cases where you cannot define the prop statically (e.g. because you
>   need to close over the component’s props and/or state)  should
>   extend React.Component instead.

I complement the code here:

```
'use strict';

class Cat extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const mouse = this.props.mouse;
        return (
            <img src="image/cat.png" style={{ position: 'absolute', left: mouse.x, top: mouse.y }} />
        );
    }
}

class Mouse extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleMouseMove = this.handleMouseMove.bind(this);
        this.state = { x: 0, y: 0 };
    }

    handleMouseMove(event) {
        this.setState({
            x: event.clientX,
            y: event.clientY
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ height: '100%' }} onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove}>
                {this.props.children(this.state)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class MouseTracker extends React.Component {
    renderTheCat(mouse) {
        return <Cat mouse={mouse} />;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ height: '100%' }}>
                <h1>Move the mouse around!</h1>
                <Mouse>
                    {this.renderTheCat}
                </Mouse>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <MouseTracker />, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

According to the article, in order to avoid negating the effect of using React.PureComponent, I can define the render prop as instance method on prototype.
But if I can not statically define the render prop, I should use React.Component instead.
I wonder in what situations, I can not statically define render prop.

Comment: sounds like a reference to `closure` - a common javascript term

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX , do you have code examples to describe the situation that prop can not be defined statically? I know `closure` but I can not see the reason why it affects how I write code here.

Comment: sorry, I can't help - no code in question, so no code in answer

Comment: Sorry, I have complement the question with code.

Comment: check this answer: https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/pull/700#issuecomment-375525559

Comment: @AndreiVoicu Thank you so much! This whole discussion solved all my confusion.